# Vanilla 1.5.1 server RandomAccessFile.write errors

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am running a 100% vanilla 1.5.1 server. I get - as soon as someone joins - tons of these here:

```
java.io.IOException: Input/output error
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.write(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.writeInt(Unknown Source)
    at acg.a(SourceFile:307)
    at acg.a(SourceFile:249)
    at ach.close(SourceFile:230)
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.close(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(Unknown Source)
    at acj.a(SourceFile:137)
    at acj.c(SourceFile:125)
    at akv.b(SourceFile:29)
    at akv.run(SourceFile:22)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

There is enough space on the harddisk, so that cannot be the issue.
Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Does the server *crash*, do something else unwanted, or is everything working and these are just harmlessly spamming the console output? I've deobfuscated the trace using MCP's class/function names, and it seems to be a problem writing Region files, but that doesn't tell me much unless I know what else is happening when this exception gets thrown.

Comment: It seems to lag the server. I am also worried that my region files might be corrupted.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I generated a new map and the problem seems to be gone. It must have corrupted the map somewhere.

Answer (score -3):

Follow these steps to fix your issue:

- Go to your minecraft server file
- Right click and open with winrar
- Go to the .gar
- Double click the ip data drive on the qb.k file

Comment: > Double click the ip data drive on the qb.k file ??
I am on a linux console, I know how to open this file, but the last line confused me.

Comment: @uncovery It's confusing because it's gibberish.